# wrap() duplicates element more than once - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pretty basic function which allows me to wrap a div tag, inside of another div tag, whenever the browser window becomes larger than **x** amount of pixels.

However, I have a strange bug which occurs once the page is resized more than once.

For starters, I'll show you the jQuery script which I am currently using, so you can get a better idea of what I am working with.

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1920px)").matches) {
        $(".navbar-inner").wrap("<div id='center'></div>");
    } else {
        var content = $("#center").contents();
        $("#center").replaceWith(content);
    }
}).trigger("resize");
```

Basically, once the window becomes larger than `1919px`, it will force the navbar to be wrapped inside of a new div tag.

The problem with this is when the page is resized more than once, the `<div id='center'>` element will be duplicated multiple times.

So, rather than the output in the **dom** being something like:

```
<div id="center">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <!-- e.t.c... !-->
    </div>
</div>
```

It will be:

```
<div id="center">
    <div id="center">
        <div id="center">
            <div id="center">
                <!-- this will duplicate over and over until at some point, it displays the navbar-inner div !-->
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <!-- e.t.c... !-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have searched almost every single thread, link, answer I could find, but I simply cannot find something that will fix my issue.

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, so all help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: `if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1920px)").matches && 
!$('#center').length) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check inside if condition that it's already wrapped or not by checking the count of element. Also you can use **[`unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)** to unwarp the element.

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1920px)").matches) {
    if (!$('#center').length)
      $(".navbar-inner").wrap("<div id='center'></div>");
  } else {
    $("#center .navbar-inner").unwrap();
  }
}).trigger("resize");
```

or check the parent is `#center` using **[`is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/)** method.

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1920px)").matches) {
    if (!$(".navbar-inner").parent().is("#center"))
      $(".navbar-inner").wrap("<div id='center'></div>");
  } else {
    $("#center .navbar-inner").unwrap();
  }
}).trigger("resize");
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this before hand. Maybe I did it incorrectly... Will attempt it now :-)

Comment: For some reason, when I resize it will glitch out, and every 2nd resize, it will take away the `<div id="center">` tag... Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the element is already wrapped and act accordingly:

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1920px)").matches) {
        if( $(".navbar-inner").closest("#center").length == 0 )
        {
           $(".navbar-inner").wrap("<div id='center'></div>");
        }
    } else {
        var content = $("#center").contents();
        $("#center").replaceWith(content);
    }
}).trigger("resize");
```